# error running through django tutorial

Tags: python, django

*Hi, Python and Django community.* I’m running through some kind of a tutorial from Youtube. I’ve got errors, which I can’t figure out.

This is my project structure:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/lol/django-developer/env16/mysite# tree
.
├── article
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db-nik-yobana.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── polls
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
└── myview.html
```

This is …/mysite/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover() 

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^basicview/', include('article.urls')), # comment out = no errors
)
```

And this is my …/article/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/1', 'article.views.basic_one'),
    url(r'^/2', 'article.views.template_two'),
    url(r'^/3', 'article.views.template_three_simple'),
```

And this is a part of my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'article',
```

When I comment out “url(r'^basicview/', include('article.urls')),” line, I’ve got no errors running development web server. Django server shows “It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.” Without comments I get an error In a web-page:

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 7)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.211.128/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 7)
Exception Location: /home/lol/django-developer/env16/local/lib/python2.7/site-       packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 40
Python Executable:  /home/lol/django-developer/env16/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/lol/django-developer/env16/mysite',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/lol/django-developer/env16/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Чтв, 30 Окт 2014 13:22:38 +0400

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
urlconf_module  
'article.urls'
namespace   
None
app_name    
None
arg 
'article.urls'
```

I can’t get it. What goes wrong? I see, it doesn’t like article.urls variable, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the entire `article/urls.py` instead of just that snippet?

Comment: a long shot, but do you have a closing `)` in your urls.py?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a ")" in the article/urls.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/1', 'article.views.basic_one'),
    url(r'^/2', 'article.views.template_two'),
    url(r'^/3', 'article.views.template_three_simple'),
) # <----- you're missing this line?
```

The error is telling that something is wrong with the urls.py file (in the article app):

```
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 7)
```

Hope that helps!